# Fast C++ numerical integration over discrete points

Tags: c++, matlab, numerical-integration

I have to do a lot of integrations over a 3D space. I have a (grid) discretization of said space (say, 30 points equally spaced in every direction) for which I know the function values I want to integrate. I cannot give a function form like f(x,y,z) = ....

Is there a fast C++ library to do so? Up until now, I used the MATLAB function `trapz(...)` which achieves just that, but I need to minimize the overhead times between the single integrations and to overall speed up my code, therefore I'm moving to C++.
As I understand it, all of the GNU Scientific Library numerical integrations need a  function handle and therefore a functional form, rendering them useless for my application.

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31866/c-numerical-integration-library), but remains unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Just summing up the values in the array gives a really good approximation to what `trapz` does, assuming equally spaced samples.

For the trapezoid method, in 1D, the two end points count only 1/2 (weighted down). In 2D, assuming a rectangular domain the four corner points should count for only 1/4, and the edge points for 1/2. In 3D you’d have 8 vertex points that count for 1/8, points along the edges of the domain that count for 1/4, and points along the faces of the domain that count for 1/2. But just counting all points with the same weight is just as valid.

To get the correct magnitude, just divide the summation result by the sample spacing. In 2D this is the x spacing times the y spacing; in 3D it is the product of the three spacings.

For non-uniform spacing the process is a bit more involved, but ultimately very easy to implement. I wouldn’t worry about finding a library that does this, it’s easier to implement from scratch than to add a dependency to your project. (Of course if you’re already using a library that implements this, it makes more sense to use the existing functionality.)